# PARALLEL DO with or without CRITICAL?

Tags: fortran, openmp

Focusing in the parallel part of the code, which of the options presented below is preferred? Any better solution? I am trying to make an average of independent realizations of `do_something`

Option 1: Using CRITICAL

```
  resultado%uno = 0.d0
  !$OMP PARALLEL DO shared(large) private(i_omp) schedule(static,1)
  do i_omp=1, nthreads
     call do_something(large, resultadoOmp(i_omp))
     !$OMP CRITICAL (forceloop)
     resultado%uno = resultado%uno + resultadoOmp(i_omp)%uno
     !$OMP END CRITICAL (forceloop)
  enddo
  !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
  resultado%uno  = resultado%uno/nthreads
```

Option 2: Avoiding `CRITICAL` (and `ATOMIC`)

```
  !$OMP PARALLEL DO shared(large) private(i_omp) schedule(static,1)
  do i_omp=1, nthreads
     call do_something(large, resultadoOmp(i_omp))
  enddo
  !$OMP END PARALLEL DO

  uno = 0.d0
  !$OMP PARALLEL DO shared(resultado) private(i_omp) schedule(static,1) &
  !$OMP & REDUCTION(+:uno)
  do i_omp=1, nthreads
     uno = uno + resultadoOmp(i_omp)%uno
  end do
  !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
  resultado%uno  = uno/nthreads
```

I couldn't use `REDUCTION(+:resultado%uno)` nor `REDUCTION(+:resultado)` in this respect, only numeric types are allowed.

The disadvantage of this approach, IMO, is that one has to dimension the derived tipe `resultadoOmp` with the number of threads. The advantage is that one avoids the `CRITICAL` clause that could affect the performance, I am right?

Answer (score 0):

> The disadvantage of this approach, IMO, is that one has to dimension the derived tipe resultadoOmp with the number of threads. The advantage is that one avoids the CRITICAL clause that could affect the performance, I am right?

Yes, you are right. It looks like you are dimensioning resultadoOmp with the number of threads anyway, so it is not really a disadvantage? Performance should indeed be better with the second part, though the two parallel regions might eat up this advantage again. Thus, you should only use a single parallel region for both parts. Depending on the running time of do_something I might even ignore parallelism for the reduction operation completely and just do a sum on a single thread after computing all uno entries in parallel:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO shared(large) private(i_omp) schedule(static,1)
do i_omp=1, nthreads
   call do_something(large, resultadoOmp(i_omp))
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

resultado%uno = sum(resultadoOmp(:)%uno)/nthreads
```

You will need to measure the various implementations with your actual setup to draw a conclusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Indeed, the time consumption of the reduction operation is negligible compared to `do_something`. One could avoid the parallelism in this region, as you propose, with almost no impact on the  efficiency.